# OpenAPI 3.0.0 reference to definitions in externalFile

Tags: docker, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm strugling with an issue on open-api 3.0.0 and swagger-ui.

I'm writing a big swagger definition and I'd like to define parameters and responses in a separate file. As a first approach I tried to follow the documentation (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) and I referenced responses in this way:

```
    '429':
      $ref: '../common-definitions.yaml#/components/responses/429'
```

but this was not working even if files path is consistent (I'm able to follow links in webstorm).

As I second attempt I googled if anyone had a similar problem and found some nice solutions as this one: https://davidgarcia.dev/how-to-split-open-api-spec-into-multiple-files
I downloaded the sample definitions and I mounted them as volumes in my swagger-ui container (yes, I'm using dockers...) but I cannot see any definition:
[image]

Can anyone help me?

Thanks, 
Laura

Update:

I run my docker with the following docker-compose:

```
version: "2.1"
services:

  my_swaggerhub_portal:
    build:
      context: .
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui:latest
    environment:
      - SWAGGER_JSON=/usr/share/nginx/html/api/openapi.yaml
    volumes:
      - /data/volume1/openapi-boilerplate-master/src:/usr/share/nginx/html/api
    dns: 10.21.1.3
    privileged: true
    container_name: my_swaggerhub_portal
    hostname: my_swaggerhub_portal
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 10.21.20.216
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 50m
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: macvlan_net
```

Comment: How do you run the container?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the original question.